# syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
class TVShow
    attr_accessor :name
    attr_accessor :tvdbID

    def initialize(showName)
        :name = showName
    end
end
```

And it gives me this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
        :name = showName
```

What I'm wanting to do is have a public variable i can use across the entire class, so that's what i'm trying to do with :name and :tvdbID.

I'm fairly new to ruby, so let me know if I'm doing this all wrong.

Comment: What is your question? (TM)

Comment: The question is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
 def initialize(showName)
   :name = showName
 end
```

to

```
 def initialize(showName)
   @name = showName
 end
```

You can also do this:

```
attr_accessor :name, :tvdbID
```

Some examples:

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def show
    puts "I am a Dog named: " + @name
  end

  def add_last_name(last_name)
    @name = @name + " " + last_name
  end

end

d = Dog.new "Fred"
d.show
d.add_last_name("Rover")
d.show

--output:--
I am a Dog named: Fred
I am a Dog named: Fred Rover
```

So instance variables are freely accessible from within the class.  However, you cannot access the instance variables in the example above from outside the class:

```
d = Dog.new "Fred"
puts d.name

--output:--
1.rb:17:in `<main>': undefined method `name' for #<Dog:0x000001010a5b48 @name="Fred"> (NoMethodError)
```

Here is how you can access the instance variables from outside the class:

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name  #getter
    @name
  end

  def name=(val)  #setter
    @name = val
  end
end

d = Dog.new "Fred"
puts d.name

--output:--
Fred
```

Those getters and setters are a pain to type--especially if you have say 10 instance variables--so ruby provides a shortcut:

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end

  attr_accessor :name, :age

end

d = Dog.new("Fred", 5)
puts d.name
puts d.age
d.age = 6   #calls age=() method
puts d.age

--output:--
Fred
5
6
```

But it is customary to write the attr_accessor line at the beginning of a class.

Comment: And my symbol will then have the value of @name?

Comment: All instance variables start with @.  @name is an instance variable.  All instance variables are private.  You can provide access to the instance variable by writing a getter and a setter method(known as accessor methods), or you can have ruby do that for you by writing `attr_accessor :name`  -- note that absence of the @.  But, you can use an instance variable across the entire class by default--that's what an instance variable is; you don't need accessor methods for that.  I'll post an example.

Comment: @Andrew, I posted some examples for you to look at.

Comment: @Andrew Just to point something out, a symbol doesn't have a value - it IS a value. Have a read of this article that explains what symbols are: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/

Comment: @Matt, 1) Trying to explain symbols to a beginner is fruitless.  2) I know what symbols are, yet I find what you posted to be utter nonsense.  No offense...I've read that in other places, so I know other people say that too.  A beginner(or anybody else?) shouldn't worry about what they are.

Comment: @7stud I think the link explains it quite well, which is why I included it. And the OP is trying to use symbols for something they aren't intended for - which is why I felt it might be useful. Symbols are great once you know what they are, and they aren't that advanced a subject!

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby `attr_accessor` is a shorthand for defining setters and getters(read mutators) of a field(instance variable). So if you wanted to create `setter` and `getter` for `name`. You would have to write extra boiler plate code around it. The class would look something like:

```
class TVShow
  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name
    @name 
  end

#Similarly other instance variables.
#Instance variables always start with @

end
```

You would instantiate an object of the class with

```
tvshow = TVShow.new
tvshow.name = 'Stack Overflow'
puts "New tv show : #{tvshow.name}"
```

`:attr_accessor :name` creates instance methods for `name`. `attr_accessor` is a method in the `Module` class.

In Ruby there is no need to define instance variables at the start of the class(like you do in other languages like Java, C++ et al). So in your constructor you would have to change from a symbol to an instance variable

```
def initialize(name)
    @name = name
end
```